# ToolBar Title showing empty in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to add actionbar toolbar in my fragment. Toolbar is displaying but the title is showing empty.
[image] 
XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Here is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tamil");
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set title of support action bar ? I can not see any `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");`

Comment: ya i tried it too. let me update it in my code above

Comment: you are retreiving the toolbar from the activity, not from your view

Comment: Or just try getActivity().setTitle("Title");

Comment: i tried this getActivity().setTitle("Title"); but it's also showing empty

Comment: why are you setting the toobar in a fragment? normaly you would do this in the activity where the fragment is located in, after doing that, you can call setTitle in the fragment

Comment: Activity is not comfortable for this process. So i want it in fragment

Comment: this is how I have setup my activity -> http://image.prntscr.com/image/65aae849849e4997b66d1a85a2dbc61f.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132179/discussion-between-dev-tamil-and-koen-van-looveren).

Comment: @DevTamil Your question is misleading. You made mention of FragmentActivity but your snippet shows that you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.As suggested by @ Koen, you should setup your toolbar in your activity instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to set your toolbar in the activity itself. Otherwise you will always need to allocate extra memory everytime you change the fragment. If you set the toolbar in the parent activity you just can call:

```
getActivity().setTitle("title");
```

in the fragment. If you do it this way no extra memory will be allocated, and it is easier to maintain.

So:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

wil go to the parent activity and will become:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

if you want to set the title in a fragment or in the activity itself:

```
getActivity().setTitle("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar.setTitle("My title");
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

TypeCaste to your ActivityName instead of AppCompatActivity like this

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
    ((YourFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((YourFragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tamil");
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As silly as this may sound, try to change the text color of your toolbar's title.

toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));